# How to prevent cloudflare from setting "x-content-type-options: nosniff"?

Tags: http-headers, cloudflare, apache2.4, x-content-type-options

According to [cloudflare docs](https://developers.cloudflare.com/ssl/edge-certificates/additional-options/http-strict-transport-security/) this header is configured in the HSTS settings, but I have HSTS disabled. I tried enabling HSTS and specifically deactivating the `x-content-type-options` header but the header is still sent. It's not a browser caching issue because the presence of the header is also visible via `curl -vv https://example.com/...`.

The issue came up after upgrading apache webserver to version 2.4 which dropped the setting for default content type (`DefaultType`), based on the reason that in modern times the browsers should take responsibility for sniffing out the type, and cloudflare's header blocks the browsers from doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Generally this option is inside the /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/security.conf (or equivalent). Check the file or search for with something like

```
grep -R nosniff /etc/apache2/*
```

If you cannot access the filesystem, I suppose you have a sort of control panel, is it?
Eg Ispconfig set this option inside his vhost configuration, in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-ispconfig.vhost and in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-apps.vhost

Comment: apache is _not_ setting `nosniff` anywhere, and the header is _not_ present when connecting directly to apache bypassing cloudflare; it's only happening with DNS proxying via cloudflare

Comment: Hum, so it is a CloudFare related problem, ok. I thought it was Apache cause you told it comes out after an upgrade of Apache itself. Well, according to [link](https://developers.cloudflare.com/pages/platform/headers/#harden-security-for-an-application) and [link](https://developers.cloudflare.com/rules/transform/managed-transforms/reference/#http-response-headers) should be a settings problem related to _header section in cloudfare, but I have no idea of where and how to search for that, sorry. I give up